# Find the well-known Christmas song

Tags: cipher, enigmatic-puzzle, seasonal

> 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 2 15 26 19 1 4 16 1 7 4 9 1 7 14 8 5 25 15 4 5 13 3 5 13 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 2 15 26 19 1 4 16 1 7 4 9 1 7 14 8 5 25 15 4 5 13 3 5 13 5 14 2 14 5 19 26 13 9 1 1 5 10 15 1 5 7 8 6 6 1 9 7 15 1 9 1 23 8 2 4 19 7 14 10 15 1 5 2 3 7 25 14 19 11 4 5 11 11 9 1 4 9 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 14 25 15 9 3 7 2 6 4 7 2 9 1 1 2 15 26 19 1 4 16 1 7 4 9 1 7 14 8 5 25 15 4 5 13 3 5 13

Yes, this is a Christmas song. It's never too early for Christmas, right? Only a couple steps and, bam, you've decoded this! Just don't rush it.

You may or may not be able to decipher the name of this song just by looking at the pattern; no, that's not enough, please explain how you came to this conclusion. Oh, and the solution isn't a mapping like "14 → A, 25 → Q, ..."! The chosen numbers are significant, e.g. you can't swap the 14s and 25s.

Hint 1:

> See this [cipher](/questions/tagged/cipher) tag? I don't think I picked that randomly, no... but, just one question: WHAT IS THE CIPHER?

Comment: For the record, this is not a bad puzzle at all. My downvote comes purely from having sworn a blood oath to combat every single christmas-y thing that rears its ugly head before halloween.

Comment: Ok, I upvoted it, coz just not that bad for that low mark...

Comment: @OmegaKrypton Doesn't matter, that's usually frowned upon (upvoting to bring the score higher).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The numbers are

> the Morse Code tree, read left to right, layer by layer. For instance, 1 is E, 2 is T, 3 is I, 4 is A... This is *still* a mapping from numbers to letters though, even though the question claims it is not: it's just a mapping that can be represented with an extra step through Morse code.
>  [image]

As Excited Raichu found, the lyrics are to

> the song "O Christmas Tree".

Answer (score 7):

Alright, this cipher has a few layers.

First,

> we gotta A1Z26 it, to get 
>  n y o i c g b f d g b i a a n y o i c g b f d g b i a a b o z s a d p a g d i a g n h e y o d e m c e m n y o i c g b f d g b i a a n y o i c g b f d g b i a a b o z s a d p a g d i a g n h e y o d e m c e m e n b n e s z m i a a e j o a e g h f f a i g o a i a w h b d s g n j o a e b c g y n s k d e k k i a d i n y o i c g b f d g b i a a n y o i c g b f d g b i a a b o z s a d p a g d i a g n h e y o d e m c e m

Then,

> I plugged this into a substitution decoder, which coughed up: 
>  o c h r i s t m a s t r e e o c h r i s t m a s t r e e t h y l e a v e s a r e s o u n c h a n g i n g o c h r i s t m a s t r e e o c h r i s t m a s t r e e t h y l e a v e s a r e s o u n c h a n g i n g n o t o n l y g r e e n w h e n s u m m e r s h e r e b u t a l s o w h e n t i s c o l d a n d d r e a r o c h r i s t m a s t r e e o c h r i s t m a s t r e e t h y l e a v e s a r e s o u n c h a n g i n g 
>  
>  using the key 
>  
>  abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz
> dwykavmocutsfenxligbhpjrzq

Now we have to do the most important step: make sure it *isn't just a substitution cipher.*

> We have to decode it using the amazing Vigenere key "aaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaaa". Any number of 'a's works, but I chose 25 because I felt like it.

Alright, cool.

> Seem familiar? Yeah, we can split this into words to get: 
>  o christmas tree o christmas tree thy leaves are so unchanging o christmas tree o christmas tree thy leaves are so unchanging not only green when summers here but also when tis cold and drear o christmas tree thy leaves are so unchanging 
>  
>  These are the lyrics to the Christmas song "O Christmas Tree".

Comment: As I said in the puzzle, the solution isn't just a mapping (which this answer essentially describes).

Comment: @Ekons Are you saying the lyrics exposed by the substitution decoder are not the ones you intended, or are you just disappointed that the method used in the solution is not the one you wanted?

Comment: @IanMacDonald The question explicitly reads that you need to provide the method, and that the method isn't a mapping from numbers to letters (well, this solution is technically letters to letters, but it's essentially the same).

Comment: @EKons I don't understand what method I'm supposed to provide- my solution was using the A1Z26 cipher and then using a substitution cipher decoder.

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu If your method meets the puzzle's requirements, I will accept it regardless of it being my own or not. However, the method you're describing is essentially a mapping like the one in the question; A1Z26 and then substitution cipher is pretty much such a mapping, rot13(r.t. a → b, l → p vafgrnq bs 14 → b, 25 → p). As long as the end result is a well-known Christmas song (worldwide, not local to one culture), and the method is fine, it gets the tick. :-)

Comment: @EKons The substitution cipher given is perfectly valid, no? I don't see any problems with this answer.

Comment: @Deusovi Hm, maybe it is, if A1Z26 counts as a valid step that makes it not a simple mapping. I'll think about it a bit. Let's not extend this discussion here too much, BTW. EDIT: Hm, considering that I've specified that the chosen numbers are significant, I don't think I'll accept this.

Comment: @EKons um... if you chose any other numbers the lyrics wouldn’t be the same?

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu They would, that's what makes this answer technically wrong. If you swap 14 ↔ 25, I'm pretty sure the lyrics will be the same. Not that you must delete this answer... :-) (*My* method is actually quite more involved, and probably unexpected...) Oh, and, using my method, no, the lyrics won't be the same.

Comment: @EKons so, under your rules for the answer, someone (not me, too much effort) could just come up with some overly long Vigenere key that decoded it A1Z26ed into any Christmas song they wanted, and you’d accept it? doesn’t that make the question too broad?

Comment: @ExcitedRaichu Hm, good point there, although I don't think there's too much potential for it to be too broad (if it is, well, coincidence :P).

Comment: @EKons Also, I’d argue that swapping two letters will alter the substitution key, thus making the method of solving entirely different.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85091/discussion-between-ekons-and-excited-raichu).

Comment: You didn't get the checkmark, but I triple-upvoted you anyways. (tried :) )

Answer (score 0):

A simple conversion to letters of the alphabet reveals:

> nyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcemnyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcemenbneszmiaaejoaeghffaigoaiawhbdsgnjoaebcgynskdekkiadinyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcem

There is repetition here, which can be made more obvious by adding line breaks:

> nyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcem (1)
>   nyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcem (1)
>   enbneszmiaaejoaeghffaigoaiawhbdsgnjoaebcgynskdekkiadi (2)
>   nyoicgbfdgbiaanyoicgbfdgbiaabozsadpagdiagnheyodemcem (1)

<sup>*Note: Insert proper decryption method.*</sup>

The trick here is that it doesn't translate to lyrics, but instead musical notes. In this case, it matches [Deck the Halls](https://www.virtualsheetmusic.com/downloads/DeckHalls.html).

Comment: "Insert proper decryption method." Hm, is this a partial answer? Because, to me, it looks like you're representing the same note with different letters, e.g. "i" and "g" at the top line.

Comment: You can consider it a partial answer. I don't intend on filling in the blanks myself since I'm usually pretty bad at "guess which cypher". The general structure matched something I found, so I ran with it.